# Left-side of html page gets clipped off

Tags: html, css, css-position, mobile-website

I've made rock paper scrissor game using html,css and js.When window is resized to small, some left portion of the page disappears .Using horizontal scrollbar i can scroll to right but not left.
I've checked for absolute positionings and negative margin but none worked.
What should i try ?
I expect to get entire page without any portion getting clipped off.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer this without the code, but I would use devtools first to see what margins are being applied. You can look at the box model for each element in your dom and see what is being applied. Also, how small are you resizing? Do you have any explicit widths? If you are sizing down to 200px, but you have a div that is 250px, it clearly is going to have overflow. Devtools can also help with analyzing different devices too. Use the tool to set a size and see how your page responds, you can change the width of elements in the devtools to see if it removes the overflow.